# How can I expose managed configuration in an app uploaded to the Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play

I have created an Android app and followed the instructions within https://developer.android.com/work/managed-configurations to set up Managed Configurations, as this app is intended to be deployed via an MDM/EMM using Managed Google Play.

However, when I upload the app it doesn't appear to recognize that the managed configuration has been defined, as when I attempt to create an App Configuration Policy within Microsoft InTune it isn't showing the specified configurations.

As an example, when I look at the Adobe Reader entry within Google Play work, I can see an entry for "This app offers managed configuration", however that is missing in our app.

[image]

Is there anything extra necessary to complete, aside from the details in the link above, in order to ensure that the Managed Configurations are available for an MDM/EMM to utilize?

Answer (score 0):

In order to ensure that Managed Configuration is exposed, the app needs to be published into Production. Managed Configurations are not exposed while a release is only within a Testing track.